# Good PIM for Windows and BlackBerry?

Tags: windows, blackberry, pim

I'm looking for a good Personal Information Manager for Windows that can sync up with a BlackBerry (8520).

Here are some requirements I came up with:

- Tasks with no due date must be carried forward until marked as done
- Scheduler/calendar must also show tasks (Outlook 2002 XP, Agendus + Outlook, Time & Chaos can't; I don't like Lotus Notes)
- French holidays
- Ideally, tasks can be divided into sub-tasks à la EccoPro

Thank you for any pointer.

Answer (score 0):

I use Google Calendar, and have that syncing with my Blackberry Bold 9700. Works really well.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I just tried Google Sync on my Blackberry, only to find out that it requires a data plan (wifi won't do) :-/